# (combinatorics)Use compositional formula $G(x)$=$\sum_{n>=0}^\ g_n{x^n\over n!}$ ,and then find $g_n$

Tags: combinatorics

$g_n$=the number of ways of selecting a permutation of length n,and then selecting a cycle of that permutation. Use compositional formula $G(x)$=$\sum_{n>=0}^\ g_n{x^n\over n!}$ ,and then find $g_n$

I set $A(x)$=$\sum_{k>=1}^\  (k-1)!{x^k\over k!}$
  $B(x)=1+\sum_{k>=1}^\  k{x^k\over  k!}$
and calculated $G(x)=B(A(x))=1+{1\over 1-x}ln{1\over  1-x}  $

I thought that $ n!$ is the number of arranging n people into groups, and then having each group sit at a circular table. I set this generating function as $ A(x)$ and generating function of choosing a cycle as $ B(x) $. Is it right?
 and I don't know how to get $g_n$ from  $G(x)=B(A(x))=1+{1\over 1-x}ln{1\over  1-x}  $

Answer (score 0):

For $n>0$ there are $a_n=(n-1)!$ ways to arrange $n$ things in a cycle, and I’ll set $a_0=0$. There are $b_n=n$ ways to choose one object from a set of $n$ objects. Thus, $G(x)=B\big(A(x)\big)$, where

$$A(x)=\sum_{n\ge 0}a_n\frac{x^n}{n!}=\sum_{n\ge 1}(n-1)!\frac{x^n}{n!}=\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{x^n}n=-\ln(1-x)=\ln\left(\frac1{1-x}\right)$$

and

$$B(x)=\sum_{n\ge 0}b_n\frac{x^n}{n!}=\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{x^n}{(n-1)!}=xe^x\;.$$

That is,

$$G(x)=\frac1{1-x}\ln\left(\frac1{1-x}\right)=\frac1{1-x}\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{x^n}n\;.$$

This means that $G(x)$ is the ordinary generating function of the convolution of the sequences $\langle 1,1,1,\ldots\rangle$ and $\left\langle 0,1,\frac12,\frac13,\ldots\right\rangle$. That convolution is easily seen to be $\langle c_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$, where

$$c_n=\begin{cases}
0,&\text{if }n=0\\
H_n,&\text{otherwise}\;,
\end{cases}$$

where $H_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k$ is the $n$-th harmonic number. If you take $b_0$ to be $1$ instead of $0$, then you get your $G(x)$, and $c_0$ is $1$ instead of $0$. In either case we have

$$G(x)=c_0+\sum_{n\ge 1}H_nx^n=b_0+\sum_{n\ge 1}H_nn!\frac{x^n}{n!}\;,$$

and $g_n=H_nn!$ for $n\ge 1$. It’s fairly well-known that $H_nn!={{n+1}\brack 2}$, the unsigned [Stirling number of the first kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind); this is the number of permutations of $[n+1]$ having exactly $2$ disjoint cycles.

**Added:** As a check, I offer a combinatorial proof that $g_n={{n+1}\brack 2}$ for $n\ge 1$. Let $\tau$ be a permutation of $[n]$, and suppose that $\sigma$ is one of its cycles; from $\tau$ and $\sigma$ we construct a two-cycle permutation $\tau'$ of $[n+1]$ as follows. Let the other cycles of $\tau$ be $\sigma_1,\ldots,\sigma_m$. Write each of these cycles with its largest element first, and then arrange the cycles in order of increasing largest elements. (This is *canonical cycle notation*.) Then concatenate the cycles and remove all but the outermost parentheses to get a single cycle. Finally, insert $n+1$ at the beginning of this cycle, call the resulting cycle $\sigma'$, and let $\tau'=\sigma\sigma'$; clearly $\tau'$ is permutation of $[n+1]$ with two disjoint cycles.

In the other direction, let $\tau'$ be a permutation of $[n+1]$ having two disjoint cycles. Let $\sigma'$ be the cycle containing $n+1$, and let $\sigma$ be the other cycle. Arrange $\sigma'$ so that $n+1$ is listed first, and erase $n+1$. You then have a cycle $(s_1,\ldots,s_k)$ for some $k$. Say that $i\in\{2,\ldots,k\}$ is a left peak if $s_i>s_{i-1}$. Break $(s_1,\ldots,s_k)$ into shorter cycles by inserting `)(` immediately before each left peak. The result is a product $\sigma_1\ldots\sigma_m$ of disjoint cycles in canonical cycle notation. Finally, let $\tau=\sigma\sigma_1\ldots\sigma_m$; then $\tau$ is a permutation of $[n]$ with the distinguished cycle $\sigma$.

These two constructions are clearly inverses of each other, so they establish the desired bijection.

**Added<sub>2</sub>:** To see why ${{n+1}\brack 2}=H_nn!$, let $\sigma\tau$ be permutation of $[n+1]$ with disjoint cycles $\sigma$ and $\tau$ written in canonical cycle notation.. Note that the first element of $\tau$ must be $n+1$. Let $k$ be the length of $\sigma$. There are $binom{n}k$ choices for the $k$ elements of $\sigma$. The largest of them must be placed first, but the remaining $k-1$ can be arranged in any of $(k-1)!$ orders, and the $n-k$ elements of $\tau$ that are not $n+1$ can be arranged in $(n-k)!$ orders. Thus, there are

$$\binom{n}k(k-1)!(n-k)!=\frac{n!}k$$

such permutations of $[n+1]$. Now sum over $k$ to see that

$${{n+1}\brack 2}=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{n!}k=n!\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k=H_nn!\;.$$

Comment: Could you show me how $ H_nn!={{n+1}\brack 2}
$ ?

Comment: @Roland: I’ve added that to my answer.